# Why Memory Consume always increase when there are no memory leaks in xcode debug navigator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory

i have some questions why my memory consume always increase when present new page but after dismiss not reduce the memory and there are not memory leaks detects
for example :

- when first run :
  [first run image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObRJs.png)
- when present new page:
  [new page image memory consume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xznqK.png)
- when dismiss the page:
  [dismiss page image memory consume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkwks.png)

i look at Debug memory graph, the Foundation always increase . like this:

- first run:
  [Debug memory graph image first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbqsI.png)
- present new page:
  [Debug memory graph image present new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx614.png)
- dismiss page:
  [Debug memory graph image dismiss page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IleoG.png)

as you can see the Foundation always increase the Heap. so the question why always increase and how we release them ? so the consume memory not increase

- example code: https://github.com/tomdwipo/simpleMemory

Comment: Can you give the example code?

Comment: here the repo https://github.com/tomdwipo/simpleMemory @HarioBudiharjo

Comment: Can you try Simulate Memory Warning in simulator's menu? Debug-> Simulate Memory Warning. See if that reduces the memory

Comment: there are not any change in memory first run 11 MB and then present 14 MB and dismiss page still 14 MB not 11 MB @OrkhanAlikhanov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checkout your code from Github and I found its a default behaviour in apple iOS.
when we call new screen that time memory get allocated into main memory and when we dismiss screen then its memory objects remain into memory until some other screens or object require memory. This memory management done by apple iOS to get best performance and avoid repetitive memory allocation task.
We can't say this is related to memory leak because in memory leak problem iOS can't deallocate memory object when more memory required by other objects.